# warning occurring following move from classic to integrated on IIS7

Tags: iis-7, .net-4.0, migration, nullreferenceexception

I have migrated my c# asp.net web application from .net 3.5 to .net 4.0 and also changed the IIS7 application pool it runs to be Integrated rather than classic. The site runs fine but I have found the following warning been recorded in the server event log:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 26/09/2011 11:19:10 
Event time (UTC): 26/09/2011 10:19:10 
Event ID: 5e750da6db8544feaede11ed88c072f6 
Event sequence: 2 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT-2-129615059474458846 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: << REMOVED >> 
    Machine name: << REMOVED >> 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 5864 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: << REMOVED >>\app_user

Exception information: 
    Exception type: NullReferenceException 
    Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.set_AsyncResult(HttpAsyncResult value)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://127.0.0.1/dummy.context 
    Request path: /dummy.context 
    User host address: 127.0.0.1 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: << REMOVED >>\app_user

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 22 
    Thread account name: << REMOVED >>\app_user
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Web.HttpApplication.set_AsyncResult(HttpAsyncResult value)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)


Custom event details:
```

Any ideas what may be causing this as I am stumped as to what it might be?

Comment: I'm having the exact same error in one of my applications that is deployed in 2008 R2 with IIS 7. Did you find out anything about this? Seems to be related somehow to Spring.NET, but I couldn't find much more than that.

Answer (score 1):

(tech difficulty: I'm having trouble to add a comment to yr question but it seems I can add it as an ansewer)

I am experiencing the same error. In this link https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPRNET-1456 they say it's a bug that "won't be fixed"

Comment: From my reading of the issue this exception should only happen at application start-up time.  If it happens often, then you need to investigate why the application is restarting, i.e. why is the app pool recycling.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and looked in the Event Viewer. Among several other errors, I had this one and another (which was an Information) :

```
Information 14/11/2011 13:54:04 Windows Error Reporting 1001    None
```

details:

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: w3wp.exe
P2: 7.5.7601.17514
P3: 4ce7afa2
P4: mscorlib
P5: 4.0.0.0
P6: 4e1823db
P7: f5
P8: 9
P9: System.StackOverflowException
P10: 

Attached files:

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_w3wp.exe_426513163e392f7b5e2712abb67e65a456d0f5_015c843b

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: b8a9aec0-0ebf-11e1-86d9-001d927c2d4c
Report Status: 0
```

So it was a stackoverflow. I guess that the error you see is just an artifact of another error. You should try to investigate for this other error. I don't say it will be a stackoverflow like mine, but it could be something else.